# What's the best way to find if a given git commit is in a tagged release

Tags: git

A common problem when dealing with fixes is to work out what releases given fixes have been applied to, i.e "is this fix in release X". What's the best way in git to check what tagged release contains a given commit id.

Going through with gitk manually eye-balling a commit in a complex merge pattern is surprisingly hard.

So far the best solution we can come up with has been to use git-cherry:

git-cherry -v $TAG $COMMIT $COMMIT^

And see if it appears with a -. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is nice and easy to do, in fact, with the following command:

```
git tag --contains f414f31
```

That will list all the tags such that `f414f31` is one of the tag's ancestors, or the tag itself points to that commit.

This is particularly useful for finding which versions of `git` contain a particular feature :)

---

*Update:*

To answer a further question in the comment below:

> Is there any easy way to find out all the equivalent commits that may have been applied to separate branches?

You can find a hash of the patch introduced by the commit by using `git patch-id` - that's the command that `git cherry`, `git rebase`, etc. use to find whether a commit has already been cherry-picked.  So, if you want to find whether the change introduced by `f414f31` was also introduced by a commit on the branch `foo`, you could always use a short shell script something like:

```
patch_id () {
    git show $1 | git patch-id | cut -d ' ' -f1
}

P=$(patch_id f414f31)

git rev-list foo | while read C
do
    P2=$(patch_id $C)
    if [ x$P = x$P2 ]
    then
        echo "Also introduced by commit $C"
    fi
done
```

If you want to look across all branches, you can replace `foo` with `--all`.  [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi)'s comment below suggests a couple of other refinements, e.g. you can add a `break` if you want to stop looking after the first match (sensible if you're only searching a single branch), or exclude all ancestors of the original commit by using `git rev-list foo ^f414f31` instead.

Jefromi's comment also reminds me that I should say a bit more about this approach.  The [documentation for `git patch-id`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-patch-id.html) explains that the ID generated is "reasonably stable" - the line numbers and whitespace can change without affecting the ID, but if you had to fix any conflicts during the cherry-pick or rebase, you may end up changing the text of the patch.  In that case, this wouldn't find the commit.

I'm sure you can also do this with an invocation of `git cherry` somehow, but I can never remember which way round the arguments are meant to go... ;)

Comment: Is there any easy way to find out all the equivalent commits that may have been applied to separate branches?

Comment: @stsquad: I've updated my answer with a short script that does that

Comment: Do note that you could sometimes still miss things; if a commit was cherry-picked with merge conflicts, the hash of the patch changes. Also it seems like you might want to make that rev-list terminate at some point, so it doesn't have to search the entire history of the repo. Maybe `git rev-list foo ^f414f31` - assume that it's been cherry-picked after the common ancestor of the two.

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks, I've updated my answer to include reference to those points.